# During Ronald Reagan's presidency, which industry sectors' workers tended to approve of him the most? And which ones disliked him the most?

Tags: united-states, economy, history, public-opinion, ronald-reagan

Ronald Reagan had a lot of support nationwide during his presidency, but there were many people who opposed him as well. It seems like different industry types tend to favor a certain political ideology more than others. What I want to know is, which particular industry sectors (i.e. manufacturing, finance, healthcare, etc) had workers who tended to approve of Reagan the most during his presidency? And which ones tended to dislike him the most?

Comment: Do you mean individual persons, individual companies, or entire "industry sectors"?

Comment: I meant entire "industry sectors." ;)

Comment: Does air traffic control count as an "industry sector"?

Comment: I don't think it generally does, but I'll allow it for this question.

Comment: I'm interested in the people working in those industries.

Answer (score 1):

I'll state that the wording of your question should be improved.  "Industry sectors" are not sentient beings and do not take action as an entity; but since government publications and op-eds are sometimes written in such a manner let's not ignore the question.

To further my point and partially answer the question, consider the 651,000 typists in the [U.S. labor force in 1986](https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/1987/06/rpt2full.pdf).  While perhaps not a direct result of President Reagan's direct policies, the [International Typographical Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Typographical_Union) ceased operation on Dec 31 of that year (did not verify the source of this bit), actually the result of a decades-long decline in demand for typesetting and similar services, brought on first by the commercial availability of enterprise computers and the eventual drop in prices of consumer products.  These folks were concentrated in urban industrial sectors such as information, financial services, and professional and business services, and would not have had much affinity for Mr. Reagan.

Finally, "which industry sectors approved/disliked Reagan" really depends on who you mean in those industries.  Whether workers, consumers, and investors approved of his social, economic, and international trade policies seems a matter of winners and losers; besides, a regime can hardly be judged on what happens solely during their term in office.  Growth in sector gross domestic product (GDP) and employment by industry is simple to find at bea.gov, but it seems your question wants to be more nuanced than to arrive at productive capacity per worker.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "disliked him the most" is easy: it was the [Professional Air Traffic Controllers Organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Air_Traffic_Controllers_Organization_(1968)) that Reagan managed to disband in 1981 due to their extremely unreasonable demands during wage increase negotiations with the government. This was also a big hit to other unions (and in turn, a boost for the economy in general, as unions are a drain on economic growth):

> Reagan's firing of the government employees encouraged large private employers like Phelps Dodge (1983), Hormel (1985–86), and International Paper (1987) to hire striker replacements instead of negotiating in labor conflicts. In 1970 there were over 380 major strikes or lockouts in the U.S.; by 1980 the number had dropped to under 200, in 1999 it fell to 17, and in 2010 there were only 11.

Comment: Do you know which other industries or organizations disliked him as well?

Comment: I will reply in a month when I'm back from my (paid) vacation.